# Wordpress Plugin development - can't see the section output

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to develop a wordpress plugin. It's just in its intial states. My main problem is that for some reason I can't see the section output - it seems that that none of the functions in the settings are being called...so in the dashboard settings I just get the output of the settingsHTML function with is being called from the add_options_page.
This is the code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Aha camp manager
 * Description: Manages camp form, submissions and emailing
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Noga Vigdor
 * Plugin URI: https://noga.digital
 * Text Domain: aha-camp-manager
 * License: GPLv2 or later
 *
 * Copyright 2023 noga.digital
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 */

class AhaCampManager {
    function __construct(){
       
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_page'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'settings'));
    
    }

function settings(){
   
    add_settings_section('aha_form_first_section', 'Form', array($this, 'parent_details'), 'aha-settings');
    add_settings_field('aha_form_parentFirstName', 'First Name', array($this, 'parentFirstNameHTML'),'aha-settings', 'aha_form_first_section' );
    register_setting('ahaplugin','aha_form_parentFirstName', array('sanitize_callback'=>'sanitize_text_field', 'default'=>'', 'section'=>'aha_form_first_section'));

  
}



function parent_details() {
    echo 'This is the parent details section.';
}

function parentFirstNameHTML() {
   
?>
 <input name='aha_form_parentFirstName' type="text">hi
<?php
}



    //creating the dashboard settings funcgtionality
function admin_page(){
    //first parameter: the title of the page that will appear on the tab,
    //second parameter: the title of the page that will be used in the dashboard setting menu
    //third parameter: only a user with 'manage_options' rights will be able to see the plugin settings
    //forth parameter: the name of the slug
    //fifth parameter: the function that will create the content for these settings page
    //Sixth parameter: the item position in the menu - in this case first position
    add_options_page('Aha Camp Manager', 'AHA Settings', 'manage_options', 'aha-settings', array($this, 'settingsHTML'), '0');
}



//The content of the plugin page once the Aha Settings is being clicked at the dashboard settings menu

function settingsHTML() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Aha Camp Manager Settings</h1>
        
        <form action="options.php" method="POST">
            <?php
                settings_fields('ahaplugin');
                do_settings_sections('aha_form_first_section');
                submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
   <?php } 

}



$ahaCampManager=new AhaCampManager();


?>
```

And this is how it looks on the website:
[image: Dashboard View]

I tried installing the plugin on another website and even twick the wp-config but nothing worked. What could be the issue? I've edited the code so many times but nothing works.
In the debug file I get this error all the time : [27-Apr-2023 13:47:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush(): Failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in C:\MAMP\htdocs\ahaoplevelse\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5309 - but I don't know if its connected (couldnt get rid of it with some wp-config definitions).